# ffmpeg drawtext leading space characters in text are getting ignored

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I am using the below arguments for drawtext in ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -vf drawtext="fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='    Hello World':x=10:y=10:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white" output.gif
```

notice the spaces before the text specified in argument, but in output the spaces before the text are getting ignored.
So how could I stop ffmpeg from doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the first space character.

```
text='\    Hello World'
```

(tested on Win7)

Comment: What if I want to leave trailing spaces instead of leading spaces ?